# Can Cisco switches block Fluke network testers

Tags: cisco, switch

I have two Fluke NetTool Series II network testers, and both network testers are showing extremely erratic behavior while connected to a new Cisco switch.  I'll try to describe the behavior below.  I'm trying to find out if cisco switches can block or deter these testers from working.

I've owned the tools for less than 1 years and though I don't use them daily I have used them quite often and I'm very familiar with the little details of how they work and behave.  You can read the list below, but suffice it to say that they just become useless.

Note:  All devices connected to this switch work just fine.

This erratic behavior starts right from the beginning.  I press **Auto Test** (this is how  you begin testing, and analyzing the network), then this happens:

- PoE light turns on for .5 seconds, goes off, then again for 1+/- seconds, then off.
- After PoE light goes off the magnifying graphic goes from "?" (normal when test first starts) to showing a digital pulse, but then back again to "?" this is odd
- After that multiple things could happen:  The device will just stop, and go back to **Auto test**; Or the tester will show that the devices (switches and or computer) are powered off, it says that when detects a NIC of a device that's not powered on.
- Looses link/connectivity to the connected device multiple times per second.

I've tried the basics: different patch cables, new batteries.  They work just fine on my previous building/network I was in, and they work just fine on my home network.

Can Cisco switches block or deter network testers from working?

Comment: Could you have a misconfigured or defective switch?

Comment: All devices connected to this switch work properly.  Even PoE phones detect power right away and turn on immediately with now problem.

Comment: `Can Cisco switches block or deter network testers from working?` - Without knowing exactly what the testers are doing it's impossible to say.

Comment: @joe Thank you for taking the time to respond.  Though I didn't tell you what exactly it does, it is a network tester, and it's the NetTool Series II from Fluke.  http://www.testequipmentdepot.com/flukenetworks/pdf/nettool.pdf.  I also think that if you know the answer to this question knowing that this is a network tester and what network testers do you'd know the answer.. but maybe that's just my opinion, I haven't gotten an answer yet.

Comment: I don't think it's a switch as the only affected device is my NetTool tester.  All other devices are fine.  The tool also works OK on other networks.... this is very clearly something affecting the NetTool specifically.